# undefined method `group' for #<Member:0x007fadb5222e40>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm receiving the following error when submitting a form to create a new object in rails application:

```
NoMethodError in MembersController#create

undefined method `group' for #<Member:0x007fadb5222e40>

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/members_controller.rb:58:in `block in create'
app/controllers/members_controller.rb:57:in `create'
```

The create method in question in my controller is as follows:

```
def create

@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])

if @user and @group and @group.group_password == params[:password]
  @member = Member.new do |m|
    m.group_id = @group.id
    m.user_id = @user.id
    m.slug = @user.username
  end
  logger.debug("#{ @member.group_id}, #{ @member.user_id}, #{ @member.slug}")
  respond_to do |format|
    if @member.save
      format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'Member was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @member, status: :created, location: @member }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
else
  redirect_to group_join_url(@group), alert: "Invalid group password"
end

end
```

line 57 mentioned in the error is "respond_to do |format|"

And just for good measure, here is my Members module:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :slug, :use => :scoped, :scope => :group

  attr_accessible :group_id, :slug, :user_id

  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be looking at things the wrong way, but it appears to be that you have a scope for `:group` and your model belongs_to `:groups` (plural) instead. There does seem to be no indication of a group attribute on your user class - there would be one if the association was singular, however.

Comment: much appreciated Fred.  The scope should have been the actual field name :group_id.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.